# DeDuplicating array of Objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working on a project that is taking in 5 similar SQL databases, and I need to detect and filter out duplicates. I think I'm on the right track, but I'm not quite there yet. I am attempting to follow these steps to accomplish this:

1. start a `.forEach()` for the main array passing in an `item` object.
2. create a filtered array via `let filtered = Array.filter(x => x.id !== item.id);` to keep from checking against itself.
3. start a `.forEach()` for the filtered array passing in `comparison` as the parameter.
4. initialize variables for similarity in Name, Phone, and Email fields.(i.e.`nameSimilarity`, `phoneSimilarity`, and `emailSimilarity`)
5. If `item.email` and `comparison.email` aren't empty, compare the strings and store the similarity percentage in `emailSimilarity` else `emailSimilarity=0`.
6. If `item.phone` and `comparison.phone` aren't empty, compare the strings and store the similarity percentage in `phoneSimilarity` else `phoneSimilarity=0`.
7. Combine `item.firstName` and `item.lastName` into an variable called `itemFullName` and combine `comparison.firstName` and `comparison.lastName` into a variable called `comparisonFullName`.
8. If `itemFullName` and `comparisonFullName` aren't empty, compare the strings and store the similarity percentage in `nameSimilarity` else `nameSimilarity=0`.
9. if any of the percentages in `emailSimilarity`, `nameSimilarity`, or `phoneSimilarity`, add `item` plus the similarity variables and `comparison.id` to the duplicates array, and splice it out of the original array.

   This is the code that I've written to follow these steps, but it appears that I'm getting duplicate entries in the duplicates array. I'm not sure why it's not working as expected, but I have a hunch that I can't really expect the original array to mutate inside the `forEach()` operation.

   ```
   fullArray.forEach(item => {
       let filtered = fullArray.filter(x => x.externalId !== item.externalId);
       filtered.forEach(comparison => {
           let emailSimilarity, phoneSimilarity, nameSimilarity;
           if ((item.email !== '') && (comparison.email !== '')) {
               emailSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(item.email, comparison.email);
           } else {
               emailSimilarity = 0;
           }
           if ((item.phone !== '') && (comparison.phone !== '')) {
               phoneSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(item.phone, comparison.phone);
           } else {
               phoneSimilarity = 0;
           }
           let itemFullName = `${item.firstName} ${item.LastName}`.trim() || '';
           let comparisonFullName = `${comparison.firstName} ${comparison.LastName}`.trim();
           if (((itemFullName !== '') && (comparisonFullName !== '')) || ((itemFullName.indexOf('Group')! > 0) && (comparisonFullName.indexOf('Group') !>0))) {
               nameSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(itemFullName, comparisonFullName);
           } else {
               nameSimilarity = 0;
           }
           if ((emailSimilarity || phoneSimilarity || nameSimilarity) > 0.89) {

           let dupesOutput = Object.assign({}, item, { similarName: nameSimilarity, similarEmail: emailSimilarity, similarPhone: phoneSimilarity, similarTo: comparison.externalId });
           dupes.push(dupesOutput);
           fullArray = fullArray.filter(x => x.externalId !== item.externalId);
       }
   });
   ```

   });

Where's the issue?

Comment: the output of `dupes` is correct, tho?

Comment: No as mentioned in the question, I'm getting multiple entries for some duplicates, and not for others. The total number of duplicates is unknown. I have an implementation of this from before I decided to standardize the objects into a single array before detecting duplicates that only gets about 6-8 duplicates across all 5 database calls. (top 100 from each for testing.)

Comment: It would help if you could also share your test data. You are using `!==` which if your sources don't agree on the actual data type, that could be an issue. (5 == '5' is true, 5 === '5' is false). Also, if the items have ids, why don't you use a map using the id's as keys to do the de-dup?

Comment: @Tezra I'm actually formatting all the compared fields as strings, and catching nulls and replacing with empty strings when I reformat the data into the export format and merge the 5 into one array. The id's could potentially be duplicated across all 5 DB's, but it's all but assured that items with the same id will NOT be duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the similarity check is working, the problem is that you're reassigning a new array to `fullArray` while still being in the `forEach` loop of the old one.

I'd suggest you use `Array.filter`:

```
var filteredArray = fullArray.filter(item => {
    return !fullArray.some(comparison => {
        if(comparison.externalId==item.externalId) 
            return false;

        let emailSimilarity, phoneSimilarity, nameSimilarity;
        if ((item.email !== '') && (comparison.email !== '')) {
            emailSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(item.email, comparison.email);
        } else {
            emailSimilarity = 0;
        }
        if ((item.phone !== '') && (comparison.phone !== '')) {
            phoneSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(item.phone, comparison.phone);
        } else {
            phoneSimilarity = 0;
        }
        let itemFullName = `${item.firstName} ${item.LastName}`.trim() || '';
        let comparisonFullName = `${comparison.firstName} ${comparison.LastName}`.trim();
        if (((itemFullName !== '') && (comparisonFullName !== '')) || ((itemFullName.indexOf('Group')! > 0) && (comparisonFullName.indexOf('Group') !>0))) {
            nameSimilarity = strcmp.jaro(itemFullName, comparisonFullName);
        } else {
            nameSimilarity = 0;
        }
        if ((emailSimilarity || phoneSimilarity || nameSimilarity) > 0.89) {
            let dupesOutput = Object.assign({}, item, { similarName: nameSimilarity, similarEmail: emailSimilarity, similarPhone: phoneSimilarity, similarTo: comparison.externalId });
            dupes.push(dupesOutput);
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: that's an intriguing solution. I was thinking that mutating the `fullArray` inside the `forEach()` was the problem, this confirms it. I like this. is `Array.some()` an actual function? or is it a placeholder that I need to find out what to use?

Comment: @ChrisRutherford no it's an actual function. [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It's named absolutely unintuitive, it should've been called `any`.

Comment: Oh Wow! yes that's hilariously named..... I guess it could be because it only returns some of the array? I'll check it out! Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRutherford that's the thing. It only returns either `true` or `false`.

Comment: ah, so that's why you only push to the Dupes array if you're going to return true. Okay that makes sense

Comment: Yes, returning true means: duplicate found, which then has `some` return `true` which gets inverted to `false`, which tells the `filter` function to filter this element out.